# iOS: How to determinie CGPoint of an object in scrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, cgpoint

While in UIView I can get CGpoint of an object like this :

```
x = self.object.frame.origin.x;
y = self.object.frame.origin.y;
```

but when I use this code when my object is in scrollView, I got the same x and y as I am in UIView. so how can I determine object CGPoint when I am in scrollView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using convertPoint to get the relative position inside a parent UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883305/using-convertpoint-to-get-the-relative-position-inside-a-parent-uiview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the contentOffset of the UIScrollView.  This will adjust your point relative to the amount of scroll applied in the UIScrollView:

```
x = self.object.bounds.origin.x + self.yourScrollView.contentOffset.x;
y = self.object.bounds.origin.y + self.yourScrollView.contentOffset.y;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CGPoint pointOfSubviewAccoringToSelfView = [self.view convertPoint:self.subview.frame.origin fromView:self.scrollView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `bounds` instead of `frame`