# Using convert(_:to:) method in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to convert a rectangle from another collectionview (cellContentCollectionView) to an equal rectangle in my root view controller.

The instance method used to do this is convert(_:to:), however I am having trouble setting the frame of the UIView in the root view controllers frame.

Here's what I have so far...

```
cellContentCollectionView?.convert((playerLayer?.frame)!, to: fullScreenPlayerView)
```

cellContentCollectionView is the collectionView that it's located in. Which happens to be in a collectionViewCell.

Any suggestions?

Comment: convert method returns a new CGRect you must use it, `let newFrame = cellContentCollectionView?.convert((playerLayer?.frame)!, to: fullScreenPlayerView)`

Comment: What is the point of the second parameter [to View: UIView?] then? I'm a little confused

Comment: is the destination view for conversion, the view were you need to put your your rectangle, you need convert `playerLayer?.frame` from `cellContentCollectionView` to `fullScreenPlayerView ` coordinate system

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I'm still having an issue when I set fullScreenPlayerView.bounds = (newFrame)!    I get the bad instructions error because it found nil.

Comment: the origin and destination both views must be inside the same view tree, if not this method can return nil

Comment: I believe they are, one is in the root view controller. The other is in a UICollectionView cell, inside a UICollectionView, inside another UICollectionView cell... Do you think that might be why it's returning nil?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465659/understand-convertrecttoview-convertrectfromview-convertpointtoview-and and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219331/convert-a-uiview-origin-point-to-its-window-coordinate-system maybe can help you

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain the exact relationship between `cellContentCollectionView` and `playerLayer`, so I'm going to assume the worst: that `playerLayer` is not a subview of `cellContentCollectionView`.

I also suspect that `playerLayer` is not actually a view at all, but is a `CALayer`. That's okay, because on iOS, a view's `frame` is always its `layer.frame`, so we can just deal with the layers.

The `frame` of a layer is in the geometry of its superlayer. So you must ask its superlayer to convert its `frame`. But, if the layer isn't transformed, you could instead ask the layer to convert its own `bounds` instead.

If you intend to use the resulting rectangle as the frame of a target layer, you must convert to the target layer's superlayer. You can't just convert to the target layer's geometry and set the target layer's `bounds`, because that doesn't update the `position` of the target layer.

Thus I think you want to write this:

```
if
    let playerLayer = playerLayer,
    let fullScreenPlayerSuper = fullScreenPlayerView.layer.superlayer
{
    let frame = playerLayer.convert(playerLayer.bounds, to: fullScreenPlayerSuper)
    fullScreenPlayerView.frame = frame
}
```

Comment: That doesn't produce any errors, however the frame produced by that code is 0,0,0,0

Comment: `print(playerLayer.bounds)` What's the output?

Comment: Also playerLayer is an AVPlayerLayer that is on top of a AVPlayer and UIView

Comment: `print(playerLayer.bounds)` produces nil

Comment: Then `playerLayer` itself must be nil.

Comment: I think there might be an issue with how I'm referencing playerLayer in my root view controller since playerLayer is lower in the hierarchy. Don't I use lazy var to access it at a higher level?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, assuming that `playerLayer` is a `UIView`.

```
guard let playerLayer = playerLayer, superview = playerLayer.superview else { return }

fullScreenPlayerView.convert(playerLayer.frame, from: superview)
```

Comment: playerLayer is an AVPlayerLayer the reason I referenced it was because I am going to need it's visual output anyways. However it is masked to a UIView so I'll try using the UIView with your code

Comment: Your code doesn't produce anything. It's as if it's producing nil, but it doesn't say it.